# At what point is Empower Spell better than Maximize Spell?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, optimization, metamagic

When I'm trying to increase the output of my spells such as [Fireball](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Fireball), [Cure Critical Wounds](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Cure%20Critical%20Wounds) or [Magic Missile](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Magic%20Missile), I can't decide whether [Empower Spell](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Empower%20Spell) or [Maximize Spell](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Maximize%20Spell) is better.

I'd like to compare only the effects of the feats, without involving the difference in spell level adjustment for each one since I'm prioritizing the output of the spell without regards to the cost involved in to cast it. However, I only have enough resources to use one of the feats, therefore I need to figure out in what cases one is better than the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Empower Spell is better when your bonus per die is higher.

If we look at [Maximize Spell](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Maximize%20Spell), it says:

> All variable, numeric effects of a spell modified by this feat are maximized. Saving throws and opposed rolls are not affected, nor are spells without random variables. A maximized spell uses up a spell slot three levels higher than the spell's actual level.

This means that any effects in the form of \$\text{x}\text{d}\text{y}+\text{z}\$ will instead be \$\text{x}*\text{y}+\text{z}\$. For example, a single magic missile deals \$1\text{d}4+1\$ damage normally, with maximize it instead deals \$1*4+1 = 5\$ damage.

If we looks at [Empower Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/empower-spell-metamagic/), we see:

> All variable, numeric effects of an empowered spell are increased by half including bonuses to those dice rolls.

How the feat works is further clarified in [this FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9o71):

> **Empower Spell: If I use Empower Spell on a spell that has a die roll with a numerical bonus (such as cure moderate wounds), does the feat affect the numerical bonus?**
>
> Yes. For example, if you empower cure moderate wounds, the +50% from the feat applies to the 2d8 and to the level-based bonus.

From this we can see that this means any effects in the form of \$\text{x}\text{d}\text{y}+\text{z}\$ will instead be \$(\text{x}\text{d}\text{y}+\text{z})*1.5\$. For example, a single magic missile deals \$1\text{d}4+1\$ damage normally, with empower it instead deals \$(1\text{d}4+1)*1.5\$ damage.

To see how to two feats compare we're going to look over [Cure Critical Wounds](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Cure%20Critical%20Wounds) since it's the least complicated to explain. The effect of the spell states:

> This spell functions like [cure light wounds](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Cure%20Light%20Wounds), except that it cures 4d8 points of damage +1 point per caster level (maximum +20).

This means that by base the spell heals for \$4\text{d}8 + \text{caster level}\$, if we empower this, it heals for \$(4\text{d}8 + \text{caster level})*1.5\$, and maximized it heals for \$4*8 + \text{caster level}\$. If we use the fact that the average value of a d8 is 4.5, we know that Maximize Spell only increases the output of the spell by 3.5 per die rolled and we know that the average of 4d8 is 18. Thus, we can get the following formulas for analyzing the spell:

\begin{array}{c|c}
 \text{maximize} & 32+\text{Caster Level} \\ \hline
 \text{empowered} & (18+\text{Caster Level})*1.5
\end{array}

We can then figure out values per die rolled using the following formulas:

\begin{array}{c|c|l}
 \text{Bonus Per Die Rolled} & \text{Caster Level}/{4}\\ \hline
 \text{Empowered Amount Per Die} & (\text{Caster Level}/{4}+4.5)*.5 
\end{array}

We can then use these formulas to produce the following table. Note that technically caster levels 1-6 are impossible to cast Cure Critical Wounds at, but are merely included for the sake of doing so.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\textbf{Caster} & \textbf{Mazimized} & \textbf{Empowered} & \textbf{Bonus Per} & \textbf{Empowered Amount} \\
 \textbf{Level}& & & \textbf{Die Rolled} & \textbf{Per Die} \\ \hline
1     & 33        & 28.5      & 0.25       & 2.375         \\ 
2     & 34        & 30        & 0.5          & 2.5\\ 
3     & 35        & 31.5      & 0.75       & 2.625         \\ 
4     & 36        & 33        & 1       & 2.75          \\ 
5     & 37        & 34.5      & 1.25       & 2.875         \\ 
6     & 38        & 36        & 1.5          & 3  \\ \hline \\ \hline
7     & 39        & 37.5      & 1.75       & 3.125         \\ 
8     & 40        & 39        & 2        & 3.25          \\ 
9     & 41        & 40.5      & 2.25       & 3.375         \\ \hline
\color{red}{\textbf{10}}    & \color{red}{\textbf{42}}        & \color{red}{\textbf{42}}        & \color{red}{\textbf{2.5}}          & \color{red}{\textbf{3.5}}\\ \hline
11    & 43        & 43.5      & 2.75       & 3.625         \\ 
12    & 44        & 45        & 3        & 3.75          \\ 
13    & 45        & 46.5      & 3.25       & 3.875         \\ 
14    & 46        & 48        & 3.5          & 4  \\ 
15    & 47        & 49.5      & 3.75       & 4.125         \\ 
16    & 48        & 51        & 4        & 4.25          \\ 
17    & 49        & 52.5      & 4.25       & 4.375         \\ 
18    & 50        & 54        & 4.5          & 4.5\\ 
19    & 51        & 55.5      & 4.75       & 4.625         \\ 
20    & 52        & 57        & 5        & 4.75
\end{array}

Looking at the table we can see that Caster Level 10 is where Empower Spell begins to increase the spell's output per die by the same value that Maximize Spell does so. Thus, at Caster Level 10, Empower Spell begins to become the optimal metamagic to apply to the spell. Using this table we can make the following statement then:

### Empower Spell becomes as good or better than maximize when your bonus per die + the average value of the die equals twice the difference between the maximum and average of the die to be rolled.

As a formula this would be:

$$(\text{Average} + \text{Bonus}) = 2 * (\text{Max}-\text{Average})$$

Solving this for d4, d6, d8, d10, d12, and d20 we get the following bonuses where Empower Spell begins to be as effective or better than Maximize Spell:

\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Die Size} & \text{Bonus}\\ \hline
4 & .5\\ 
6 & 1.5 \\ 
8 & 2.5 \\ 
10 & 3.5 \\ 
12 & 4.5 \\
20 & 8.5 \\
\end{array}

Comment: This analysis is all correct, but doesn’t take into account the fact that Maximize Spell increases spell level by 1 more than Empower Spell. That’s **huge**, given the exponential scaling of spells.

Comment: It may be worth a footnote, but OP specifically states "without involving the difference in spell level adjustment for each one since I'm prioritizing the output of the spell without regards to the cost involved in to cast it." (probably edited shortly after, even in response to, this comment)

Comment: @Ifusaso nope, that was there from the start. The only thing edited in is that saying use both feats isn't allowed.

Answer (score 4):

### One is not strictly better than the other

It depends on the spell.

**Fireball**

As a 3rd level spell, you need to be 9th level to Empower it and 11th level to Maximize it so, to compare apples with apples we'll assume an 11th level caster. The spell will do 10d6 \$\times\$ 1.5 damage or 60 damage respectively. It's easy to [show](https://anydice.com/program/194a0) that Empower is better 15.65% of the time and worse 79.5% and as good 4.85%.

**Cure Critical Wounds**

Here you need to be at least 13th level to use both. [So](https://anydice.com/program/194a0), Empower is better 54.2% of the time, worse 37.6% and as good 14.06%

**Magic Missile**

Magic Missile is tricky because each dice is increased by 50% and rounded down individually. You need to be 7th level giving you 4 missiles. Making [empower](https://anydice.com/program/194a0) better 42.97% of the time, worse 42.97% and the same 14.06%.

### What's going on?

Putting aside *Magic Missile* for the moment because each dice is rounded individually, Empower is better than Maximize when:

\$
1.5(n\text{d}\Delta+b)>n\Delta+b
\$

which we can algebraically rearrange to:

\$
n\text{d}\Delta>{2\over3} (n\Delta-0.5b)
\$

where \$n\$ is the number of dice, \$\Delta\$ is the number of sides on the dice and \$b\$ is the fixed bonus.

If we consider the random variable that \$n\text{d}\Delta\$ is we can say a few things about it. It is the sum of \$n\$ independent [discrete uniform variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) running from \$1\$ to \$\Delta\$. This distribution is symmetric about the mean which is \$n{{\Delta+1}\over 2}\$.

Because it's symmetrical, Empower is probabilistically better than Maximise when this mean is greater than the right-hand side of the above equation, i.e.:

\$
\begin{align}
n{{\Delta+1}\over 2}&>{2\over3} (n\Delta-0.5b)\\
3n\Delta+3n&>4n\Delta-2b\\
-n\Delta+3n&>-2b\\
{n\Delta-3n\over 2}&<b\\
n({\Delta-3\over2})&<b\\
\end{align}
\$

So, without a bonus to the roll, Empower is better than Maximize if you roll any number of d2 and as good for any number of d3 and worse for any number of d4 or higher.

So, for *Fireball*, which uses d6's and has no bonus, Maximize is always better.

For *Cure Serious Wounds* \$n=4\$, \$\Delta=8\$ and \$b=13\$, the inequality is satisfied so Empower is better.

For *Magic Missile* because each dice is rounded down individually, the possible results of \$1\text{d}4+1\$ are \$\{3,4,6,7\}\$ which is symmetrical about the Maximized result of 5 so they are equally good.